# Qlik Sense: How to accept user input to a column in a table and write back to source

Tags: input, user-input, qliksense

In Qlik Sense, I have a task to allow users to enter comments next to each row in a table. The source is currently from an excel file but if I can figure this out, it will be from a database. The goal is to have the user's comments be written back to the source.

I am stuck currently on how to allow the user to enter comments in the existing table from Qlik Sense.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Qlik does not have this capability. Qlik (and the other similar tools) don't write data back. They consume data.

Said that ... I had similar requirement few years ago - users to be able to write comments based on the data that is displayed (based on the current selections). My solution was to write QV extension that sends the selections and user input data to web server (NodeJS in my case) and the web server was storing the data in text file which was then consumed back from Qlik. With this approach the web server can do whatever you want with the data - write files, write in db, trigger actions etc.

But again - there is no way to write back to the database from the UI with the default tools

Repo with the QV extension and the server - https://github.com/countnazgul/qv-add-comment